# get string length from resources before variable inserted

Tags: java, android, string

In one of my `TextViews` I had like to set some of the text in a bold font like this:

[image]

In order do so I'm using the following:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(itemView.getContext().getResources().getString( R.string.ActivityIShared_with, sharedTo.get( getAdapterPosition() ) ));
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 11, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
tv_SharedWith.setText(sb);
```

Where

```
<string name="ActivityIShared_with">Shared with: %1$s</string>
```

As you can see this code works. However, I needed to count the length of the `R.string.ActivityISharedwith` manually until the part of `%1$s` which is 11 in order to make it bold.

Maybe in a few days, I will change that sentence and I would like to avoid counting its length every time.

How can I get the length of it but without the part of `sharedTo.get( getAdapterPosition() )` ? the string without the variable.

Thank you

Comment: did you try regex? ` String mydata = "String with: 1s$s";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z, ]+:");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);`
Something like that you neet to make pattern as static variable because that consume a lot each compilation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, You can use bold  tags in your string and display it in HTML form. See the code below

`String text = itemView.getContext().getResources().getString( R.string.ActivityIShared_with, sharedTo.get( getAdapterPosition));`

`SpannableStringBuilder styledString;`

`if(SDK_INT > N) styledString = (SpannableStringBuilder) Html.fromHtml(,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)  else styledString = (SpannableStringBuilder) Html.fromHtml(result)`

`tv_Sharewith.setText(styledString.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you are basically trying to concate string with some style. You can try this straight forward to solve your problem with little modification

Add this method

```
public static SpannedString buildString(String boldText, String regularText) {
    final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(boldText);
    builder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD), start, builder.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.append(regularText);
    return new SpannedString(builder);
}
```

and change

```
<string name="ActivityIShared_with">Shared with: %1$s</string>
```

to

```
<string name="ActivityIShared_with">Shared with:</string>
```

and use the method

```
buildString(context.getString(R.string.ActivityIShared_with), sharedTo.get(getAdapterPosition()));
```

This way you don't have to keep count of text length referring `ActivityIShared_with`